# Check if login details match those in database

Tags: c#, mysql

I am creating a login system but I dont know how to handle the login information (username and password)

Here is my code:

```
 MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MySQLConnection);
            connection.Open();
            string result = string.Empty;
            MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick="+nick.Text+" AND password="+pass.Text+" LIMIT 1;";
            MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            result = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            connection.Close();
            if (result.Length!=0)
            {
                int id;
                label3.Text = "Loged.";
                dataReader.Read();
                id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]);
                game g = new game();
                g.label1.Text = Convert.ToString(dataReader[1]);
                g.label84.Text = Convert.ToString(id);
                this.Hide();
                g.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = "Bad information.";
            }
```

This doesnt work: how do I check if the user exists with this information(username and password) and that the details are valid?

Comment: If this is a real system, I hope you aren't actually going to store the plaintext password in the database!

Comment: Do yourself a favor and read up on proper techniques for storing passwords in a database. This might be a good starting point: http://blog.codinghorror.com/rainbow-hash-cracking/

Answer (score 1):

Following should be done:

1. Use Parameterized Query and `using` statement
2. Use only `MySqlDataReader` no need of `ExecuteScalar`
3. Check if `dataReader.HasRows`
4. Read values from reader and perform required action.

Code:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MySQLConnection))
{    
   connection.Open();            
   MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick=@nick AND password=@pass LIMIT 1;";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nick", nick.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass.Text);

   using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {            
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {                
            label3.Text = "Loged.";
            dataReader.Read();
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(dataReader[0]);
            game g = new game();
            g.label1.Text = Convert.ToString(dataReader[1]);
            g.label84.Text = id.ToString();
            this.Hide();
            g.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Text = "Bad information.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your select statement. You have to use single quote in where condition for the string data types
Try the following query

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick='"+nick.Text+"' AND password='"+pass.Text+"' LIMIT 1;";
```

Also you can make the query parameterized, which is more efficient.